# How to link PFObject to an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsarray, pfobject

I have a `PFObject` that I would like to equal an array but it says incompatible pointer.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *foundUser;

PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
        [query whereKey:@"username" containsString:searchText];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                if (objects.count > 0) {

                    self.foundUser = objects.lastObject;

                }
```

I don't want this line `self.foundUser = objects.lastObject;` to say `.lastObject` I want to get all objects in the array but it says incompatible pointer of `PFObject` to `NSArray`.

How can I get it to have all object so it shows all objects and not last object?

EDIT:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    if (self.foundUser) {

        return 1;

    } else {

        return 0;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (self.foundUser) {

        return 1;

    } else {

        return 0;

    }

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFUser *user = self.foundUser;
    if (self.foundUser) {

        //set the label as the foundUsers username
        cell.textLabel.text = self.foundUser.username;

    }

        if ([self isFriend:self.foundUser]) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFUser *user = self.foundUser; 
    PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"friendsRelation"];

    if ([self isFriend:user]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        for (PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
            if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
                [self.friends removeObject:friend];
                break;
            }
        }
                [friendsRelation removeObject:user];

        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [self.friends addObject:user];
            [friendsRelation addObject:user];

    }

    [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeed, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

    }];

}

#pragma mark - helper methods

-(BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser *)user
{
    for (PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
        if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of foundUser to `NSArray` and then change the line to `self.foundUser = objects` (rename foundUser to foundUsers maybe to make it more clear).

Currently, when simply removing `.lastObject`, you're telling the system that `foundUser` is of type PFUser and you want to assign it a value of type `NSArray` which does not work in a strongly-typed world.

Comment: i need the self.foundUser as PFUser as i use it later on to add and remove friends and do other queries. is there a way to get the array to match the PFUser without warnings?

Comment: Well you either extract an item from the array (using `.lastObject`) for example or you change your logic as I said. The search could return multiple users anyways, how would you be sure that the one you take from the array is the correct one?

Comment: i can't be sure as i have to type almost the exact username to get user, i will edit my question above to include the rest of my code, so we can see how to modify it to still behave the same.

Comment: My answer still stands, if you want _ONLY_ one user from the search results, use `.lastObject`, if you want to display all search results (the result would be an array of PFUser), change the type of `foundUser` to `NSArray`. You can of course use `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:` instead of `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:`, that would then only return one user max. if any matches your query

Comment: if i change self.foundUser to NSArray would the rest of my code still work??